# How To Make a program for grade of students without if else statements in python

Tags: python, if-statement

Actually, I am a beginner. So Help Me Accordingly. I am Confused, How We Will Be Able To Generate The Same Output Without using if_else, By Using Basics.

```
#We Really Stalk Code!! :)
M = int(input("Enter The Marks Of Maths(Out OF 100) "))
S = int(input("Enter The Marks Of Science(Out OF 100) "))
E = int(input("Enter The Marks Of English(Out OF 100) "))
TOT=M+S+E
print("Total Marks",TOT,sep=" ")
PER= (M+S+E)/3
print("Percentage",round(PER,2),sep=" ")
#Now I want The Below Code To Be Run Without The Use Of if_else
if(PER>50):
  print("A")
elif(PER>0):
 print("B")

elif(PER==0):
  print("C")
```

Comment: Share your snippet of code that you need help to transform.

Comment: The majority of writing code is simply about understanding the requirements. Without expected inputs and expected outputs, there is nothing that can be written. Think about precisely what your program needs to do, make an attempt at solving it, and come back with more specific details. Then we will be able to assist you.

Comment: What does the [tag:basic] tag have to do with the question?

Comment: This question also has nothing to do with Visual Studio Code.

Comment: @PiyushBaweja I get it, but the code is the same in any editor, so it's completely irrelevant.

Comment: It'll be recommended that you read the descriptions of the tags before using them on your questions. That way there won't be any confusions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@NickBailey 's answer is the simplest and probably the best route without if-else statements.

You can also use boolean logic to figure out if the grade should be an A, B, or C with a dictionary.

```py
# Figure out if it's an A, B, or C (only one can be True)
is_a = PER > 50
is_b = PER <= 50 and PER > 0
is_c = PER == 0

# Assign key,val pairs to each grade
grade_values = {
    is_a: "A",
    is_b: "B",
    is_c: "C",
}

# Since only one grade can evaluate to True, grade_values[True] will return the correct grade
grade = grade_values[True]

print(grade)
```

Comment: can't it be more basic

Comment: @PiyushBaweja meaning? It's a list, a dict, and a while loop. It can be shortened though

Comment: Even, I am getting error

Comment: I edited it a couple times to fix some quotes, copy it in full

Comment: @PiyushBaweja I was able to make it a lot more simple

Answer (score 0):

If else *is* the basics. There's literally no more basic construct in programming. Any alternative mechanism of accomplishing this is going to use a more complicated construct (a data structure, a goto or a loop)

Python does have alternative control flow statements. It has `goto`, and if can be implemented using `while` and break as follows

```
while per > 50:
   print("A")
   break
```

But `if-else` is always the correct way to do this in Python.

Artificial restrictions don't teach you to be a good programmer. You don't learn to become a good writer by writing an entire essay without using the letter e. You don't learn to become a good footba player by not using your feet. You don't become a better cook by cutting all your vegetables with a spoon.

Comment: Yes, Thanks! But We Were Given Homework With Some Limitations in Code

Comment: Then your teacher is a bad teacher and should feel bad. Try the while loop thing or look up goto

Comment: Lol, Thanks For Your Precious Time. I did it :)

Answer (score -3):

An alternative to if else in python is switch case in python. Implementing switch case in python can be acheived with the help of dictionary in python.

Comment: Yes, it's also a great idea but can't we do it by just using basics? we can't use switch!

Comment: Python doesn't have a switch statement.

Comment: Ohh, I was not knowing. then How? we will do this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).